# Determine list() being used is Built-in Type or Built-in Function?

Tags: python, list

When looking through the Python documentation for `list()` there seems to be two options. The Built-in Types `list()` and Built-in Functions `list()`. I'm wondering how do you know which one is being used when reading through some code.

For instance if I have a simple function that reverses a list:

```py
def reverse(l):
    return list(reversed(l))
```

How to do you determine whether the `list()` being used in this code is the Built-in Type `list()` or the Built-in Function `list()`?

Comment: There is only one. The built-in `list` is *always a type*.

Comment: The `list()` is a constructor call for the class `list`, which defines the type `list`

Comment: You cant use a function and an instance of a type interchangeably. The function `list` returns an object of type list. Both are at use in your function because you call `list` the function and return `list` the type. You can type `type(list)` and `type(list())` at the REPL to see the difference.

Comment: `list` has been a function in older Python versions. Nowadays it's a type. From the interface perspective it does not make any difference.